# AdColony 2.0 iOS

Tags: ios6

Here's what I get:
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_CMTimeMake", referenced from:
      -[ADCVideo replay] in libAdColony.a(ADCVideo.o)
      -[ADCVideo resume] in libAdColony.a(ADCVideo.o)
      -[ADCVideo setupPlayer] in libAdColony.a(ADCVideo.o)
  "_kCMTimeZero", referenced from:
      -[ADCVideo replay] in libAdColony.a(ADCVideo.o)
      -[ADCVideo resume] in libAdColony.a(ADCVideo.o)
      -[ADCVideo setupPlayer] in libAdColony.a(ADCVideo.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I am trying to setup the new sdk.  Just took out the old sdk files (from previous version), and plopped in the new ones.  Libraries and linking look to be ok, or setup as per guide.  What else could it be?

Comment: CoreMedia it was, GRACIAS!

Comment: The AdColony SDKs include a PDF that lists the differences from previous versions; I believe this includes any new frameworks that are required.

Answer (score 3):

Those functions are from the framework CoreMedia. Make sure you are linking with CoreMedia framework.